# Virtualbox in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I have two layers virtualisation. First virtualbox on windwos 8.1, virtual machine ( 3Cores, 8Gb Ram, AMD-V V-TX ubuntu x64 14.10).

1)In this virtual machine, i installed virtualbox, want this configuration ( 1Cores, 1Gb Ram, AMD-V V-TX ubuntu x64 14.10), but i can't enable AMD-V V-TX -> i can't  install ubuntu x64?(

2)Later i want delete first level virtualisation, i want install first virtual machine like real os for more performance, can i made image this virtual machine in virtual box, and install like bootable flash drive?

Comment: Why do you have to use two levels, why not simply create the new VM in the top-level Windows VirtualBox?

Comment: Do you want to create a bootable image of the VM running on top of your OS that is running on top of your hardware?

Comment: @cutteeth Yes, when i will be os with one virtual box.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Flagged for migration to SuperUser.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox (as of 4.3.20) does not support nested hardware virtualization functionality. When you run a guest within VirtualBox, the guest will not be able to use hardware virtualization features (VT-x/AMD-V). Therefore, installing a guest within a VirtualBox guest, you are forced to only use software virtualization for this nested guest.

Until VirtualBox implements nested hardware virtualization (VT-x/AMD-V passthrough) you will not be able to use AMD-V/VT-x features inside the guest and anything you run inside the guest.

Update: VirtualBox 5.0.x also lacks nested virtualization feature.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the panel on the left that lists your VMs and click on clone. Your VM will be cloned and filename will be displayed. Also if you want to copy that to a portable storage medium, You can try copying that particular folder by the name of cloned VM.